# Mysql + GMAPs - Select from DB and count distance

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, distance

I have MySQL table with some libraries. I need to make SQL query in PHP, which will select library by ID, and count distance. This is invalid query. Where I'm doing mistake in this query ?

```
$query = "SELECT *,  
    ( 6371 * 
        acos(
            cos(radians(" . $center_lat . ")) *
            cos(radians(lat)) *
            cos(radians(lng) - radians(" . $center_lng . ")) +
            sin(radians(" . $center_lat . ") ) *
            sin(radians( lat ) )
        )
    ) AS distance
FROM `libraries`
WHERE id = ". $id ."
LIMIT 0 , 1";
```

Comment: You've hard coded the text `lat` and `lng` in the query string, instead of using _variables_ by the same names which should have numbers in them.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didnt understund. lat and lng are from MySQL

Comment: Please include the error message in your question.